# Using EF Code First to key tables/databases on User ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to setup a user preferences table that can be edited in a MVC View by a user. The preferences will be mainly selectable by a dropdown list. There will a couple of dozen preferences. I am using EF code first with MVC5.

As an example. Say there is a master table that contains available preferences.

```
ShirtColor     Blue
ShirtColor     Red
PantColor      Black
PantColor      Blue
SockColor      White
SockColor      Brown
```

Then, when a user edits their preferences that will see a series of dropdown allowing them to change their preferences:

```
Shirt Color:   Blue    <--- Dropdown w/options Blue, Red. Current setting selected.
Pant Color:    Black   <--- Dropdown w/options Black, Blue. Current setting selected.
Sock Color:    White   <--- Dropdown w/options White, Brown. Current setting selected.
```

The user's preferences will be used as defaults that are applied to product selections in other parts of the site. There is a need to save all user's product selections which could result in a history of 1000's of rows per user.

My concern is database design. Knowing that EF does not handle cross database queries easily, and knowing that these tables will need to be keyed on the user ID, can anybody guide me toward a good solution with respect to the database design using EF code first?

Is there a performance consideration for creating all of the required tables in a single database? Or should I segregate some of these tables across 2 databases? If the latter, how do I key this data by user ID?

The above example scenario greatly simplifies my requirements. The actual data is for Unit of Measure preferences, but it illustrates the idea - a master table of preferences with their definitions that each user can specify in their user profile. My biggest confusion/concern is how I can use EF code first to use the user ID to keep track of this data.

Comment: Instead of multiple databases, have you considered multiple dbcontexts with groups of tables from one database? I've never seen or done this with code first, but you may want to look into it. I guess the biggest hurdle would be the shared Users entity. There are a ton of resources online you can look into.

Comment: I may have overlooked ideas and examples online. I've search and reviewed so many. I'd like to keep it all in the same database for sure. It seems to simplify the whole application - but something keeps tugging at me saying this might be easier, but it isn't right and should be in separate databases.

Comment: How many tables are in the database? Are they all logically linked? Do you feel like you need separate databases because one table could contain thousands of rows? If so, that's not a problem as long as your queries are done correctly.

Comment: I'm not a database architect by any means. There is the Identity user data of course. Then there is data which is mostly static, like string translations for globalization/localization, supported countries and state/provinces. There is also a table for unit of measure and rules for conversion (US to metric, feet to meters, etc). Much of which is static data and 'seems' to belong in it's own database away from the Identity user database. There will also be a product database. I'm starting to wonder why I would use more than 1 database. It seems that a single database might be best/ok?

Answer (score 1):

> **There is a need to save all user's product selections which could result in a history of 1000's of rows per user.**

You don't have to store each User's setting in a single row. You might only need two columns. First column is user id, second column is the user setting in a formatted value (could be a json).

```
User Id   Setting
A         {"ShirtColor": "Blue", "PantColor" : "Black", "SockColor" : "Brown"}
B         {"ShirtColor": "Red", "PantColor" : "Black", "SockColor" : "White"}
C         {"ShirtColor": "Blue", "PantColor" : "Blue", "SockColor" : "White"}
```

> **Knowing that EF does not handle cross database queries easily**

I'm wondering, which ORM that provide cross database query easily?

> **Is there a performance consideration for creating all of the required tables in a single database? Or should I segregate some of
>   these tables across 2 databases? If the latter, how do I key this data
>   by user ID?**

Above solution I think is sufficient, unless there is really a lot, I mean, A LOT of settings, then you need to find the right column type, either varchar or varbinary (which you will need to save / read the data as byte and you can also compress the data for more compact data).

> **My biggest confusion/concern is how I can use EF code first to use the user ID to keep track of this data.**

Just use a normal Foreign Key concept.

Comment: I've been reading on NHibernate which would allow cross database queries. I'm just wondering about the product selection history containing so many 1000's of rows and being in the user database. Maybe it wouldn't make any difference for performance to put that in a different table. I also like the idea of setting preferences in a single field. It seems to be a scalable option? I mean, I could add additional preferences down the road without any change in the table schema. Using this approach would allow me to use EF code first for these needs. What about the history with 1000's of rows?

Comment: I agree, it might not make any difference to put in different table, but this one is more simple, i have used this method to store user profile for table state (ordering, grouping, hiding / showing, filtering, etc) combined with other settings, but I suggest you to do proper stress testing before deciding to go this way.